# Gradle "... occurred starting process 'command 'npm''" on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, intellij-idea, gradle

I have MacOS with IntelliJ Idea installed. I'm using Gradle (gradle-2.4) for building the project. I have NodeJS and NPM installed on the Mac and available from the shell.

```
MacBook:~ user$ node -v
v4.2.2
MacBook:~ user$ npm -v
2.14.7
```

When running Gradle task that uses NODE/NPM, it fails with the following error (in current example it is NPM).

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':module:task'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'npm''
```

The error stack trace from Gradle is the following.

```
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':module:task'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'npm''
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:196)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:325)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:83)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start 'npm'
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:65)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "npm" (in directory "/<project path>"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    ... 4 more
```

So it looks like Gradle is trying to find NPM in the project absolute directory and doesn't use Mac PATH environment variable. Anyone knows how to avoid/workaround this? I cannot use absolute path for NODE/NPM as the team is shared and using different OSes (Linux, MacOS). Any ideas? :)

Comment: Could you please include a relevant part of `build.gradle` script?

Comment: I'm using plugin "com.moowork.node" version "0.11" and one of my task depends on "npmInstall".

Comment: With gradle 2.8 it works perfectly fine. Do you have npm and gradle correctly added to $PATH variable?

Comment: Yes, I have provided the output of terminal console executing NPM and NODE from home directory. It works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. However it seems you have misconfigured sth.

Comment: In my case none of the above solved the issue. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71061556/6266845) solved it.

Answer (score 113):

I stop the gradle daemon by running

```
$ ./gradlew --stop
```

rerun the gradle command and fix it.

Comment: It works for me.  I just use ./gradlew assembleRelease meet this question.  So  i  use  react-native start, But, maybe the cache lay to this question. So I use ./gradlew --stop. I reuse the command:  ./gradlew assembleRelease OK!  Thanks a lots!

Comment: Is it a bug, any one filed an issue?

Comment: Thanks, it did the job! I don't know why it happened tho.

Comment: how to rerun the gradle?

Comment: this should be accepted, it seems like if you the new install node cannot applied to the current running gradlew deamon

Comment: that worked for me today with RN 0.70.6: 'command 'node'' wasn't found. thank you

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar issue and in my case, problem was that when I ran it from IntelliJ, Gradle was unable to access path to find out where node / npm is. I was using the gradle-gulp-plugin and enabling automatic download of node resolved the problem.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('be.filipblondeel.gradle:gradle-gulp-plugin:0.1')
    }
}
node {
    // Version of node to use.
    version = '0.12.0'

    // Enabled the automatic download.
    download = true
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and got it resolved by running the command:

```
gradle --stop
```

Comment: And also you need eg: `inputs.dir(new File('src'))`
  `outputs.dir(new File('dist')`
 in task

Answer (score 7):

Might be usefull for someone:

In my case the problem was, that I had Android Studio running.
Had to quit it first, then everything worked fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue attempting to run Gradle tasks that executed commands such as node and npm from the Gradle plugin in Intellij.  You can see from the stack trace that the Gradle plugin is attempting to execute external system commands and it is getting errors such as this:

```
WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - error=2, No such file or directory 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: error=2, No such file or directory
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:228)
```

You can reproduce this error from the command line if you remove the executables (ie node, npm) from the path, which tells me that something about the plugin is not honoring the environment path.

My Gradle plugin is using the projects gradlew (gradle wrapper version 2.3), so I attempted to point the plugin at a more recent Gradle installation on my system (version 2.10) and it worked.

I then resolved my issue by regenerating the gradle wrapper for my project and then setting the IntelliJ Gradle plugin to point back to my wrapper.

I have no idea what the original problem was.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this is trivial it turns out. Solution is applicable to ANY application.

The reason for the error is that none of the visual apps on Mac OS X use a user shell so whatever you have in your local profile settings such as `~/.bash_profile` simply does not take when Studio is launched. There is a good workaround:

1. from terminal, go to this directory or where ever your Studio app (or any other app) is installed:

```
cd /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS
```

2. Move the studio executable to `studio_app` (or whatever is your executable name)

```
mv $executable$ $executable$_app
```

3. Create a new text file, call it `$executable$`, and populate it like this. Here I am using my `bash_profile`.

```
#!/bin/sh    
. ~/.bash_profile
logger "`dirname \"$0\"`/$executable$_app"
exec "`dirname \"$0\"`/$executable$_app" $@
```

4. Close the studio file. From shell change permissions:

```
chmod +x $executable$
```

And that is it. Relaunch Studio app normally and now it has inherited all your settings from `bash_profile`, including path to node etc.

Substitute `$executable$` with the name of your exe file. For Android Studio it would be just studio. For IntelliJ it should be just intellij (double check).

Comment: This method no longer works with Studio 2.2.2 as the app seems to be signed. I did get it to work by creating Automator Application that runs a shell script with 2 steps: sourcing the profile and opening the real Android Studio app. Seems to work fine. What a royal pain in the ass...

Comment: Moonwalker how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Might be helpfull:

> sudo launchctl config user path $PATH

"To take effect might have to restart your machine"

Comment: It's always good to explain what your answer *actually does* when posting, this way OP can learn from it.