# Local images are not visible in React-Native app release build

Tags: image, local, release, react-native

In my react-native app I have ["src"](http://postimg.org/image/ak6w7cbk3/) folder that includes a *Images* folder and screens folder.My *screens* folder have various *components* where I am uing local images from *Images* using following code.

```
<Image source={require('src/Images/logo.png')} />
```

*logo.png* is an image placed in Images folder, there are many more such images referenced like this.Now all these images are shown pretty well in development mode but when I generated the release apk using gradlew assemblereleaseand installed the apk on my device all images referenced in this manner disappear somewhere.

My react-native version is 0.40.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solved by following answer of [Chiranjhivi Ghimire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175416/how-to-use-offline-bundle-on-android-for-react-native-project/)
Steps -

1. Created assets folder at ../android/app/src/main/
2. copy and paste this command in command prompt

> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/

3. enter this command in cmd gradle assemblerelease.
4. done

equivalent solution for ios can be found at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354998/react-native-ios-app-not-showing-static-assets-images-after-deplying)

Comment: If your React Native project directory does not have index.android.js this command works for me                                              " react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/"

Comment: I am running these commands:

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`
`cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease && ./gradlew installRelease`

But some of the images are not coming while others are coming.

Comment: @khateeb that is weird, but with the latest version of react-native you should replace "index.android.bundle" with "index.bundle" see Mesorale's comment

Comment: @ManjeetSingh I tried that and it did not make a difference.

Comment: I am also having this issue. Running `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file app/index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/` command did not help. Any suggestion?

Comment: Already bundled. Just switched from ./gradlew bundleRelease to ./gradlew assembleRelease and I cannot get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

try running this 
npm start --reset-cache