# React-native : Why bundled image doesn't show if no network?

Tags: android, react-native

I have images I set up with require() in the constructor in the state.

```
this.state = {
  image: require('./static/image/noimage.png'),
}
```

I print this image in render() like this :

```
<Image source={this.state.image} style={{ width: 120, height: 80 }} />
```

Then I build an APK with :

```
EXPO_DEBUG=false expo build:android -t apk
```

The APK works perfectly in the android emulator and on a real phone, but images only show if network is enabled (WiFi or mobile connection). There is no error message,there is only reserved white space in place of the images.

I need this app to be able to work with no connection at all.

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local images are not visible in React-Native app release build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41937443/local-images-are-not-visible-in-react-native-app-release-build)

Comment: Instead of using expo, I finally used ./gradlew assembleRelease with a configured key (as explained in the react-native documentation), and it works ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  from react-native-elements library`npm install react-native-elements`