# React Native Release Signed APK crash on app start

Tags: android, react-native, android-signing

I have an issue with react native release APK.

The app run on debug mode but it crash immediately on release mode

Some Phone it will be installed but when i will run it then it crash immediately and some other phone it will not installed Here is my app like looking this...
[image]

**Here is my packege dependencies list**

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.8",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.24.2",
    "react-native-otp-inputs": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.9.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
},
```

**And my android/build.gradle file is -**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    }
}
```

**My android studio log cat crash ....**
[image]

Comment: post the crash logs

Comment: Yeah, you can see crash logs in Android Studio, BUT based on my experience in React Native there is a high chance that your .apk missed js bundle. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175416/how-to-use-offline-bundle-on-android-for-react-native-project

Comment: Crash logs pic updated here please check again post @AADProgramming

Comment: Please check the crash logs pic which i updated the post @DNA.h

Comment: can you include your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

based on your crash log, and the fact that app runs in debug it is very likely that you have bundling problem. Run this command again in order to create a fresh new bundle

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

or

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

if you don't have index.android.js, and create a new release

Comment: can you also provide contents of "index.js" or "index.android.js" and contents of "android/app/src/.../MainApplication.java" too

Comment: this link i provide two files..
https://drive.google.com/open?id=12s3tp1oSwW4N9-golbhhMhVkLQRAIDXk

Comment: you can see this files @DNA.h

Comment: your crash log tells that Notification was not found. and in your package list i cannot see package relatable to Notifications. so i assume you are missing a "react-native link" or "/android/gradlew clean" somewhere. It would be definitely of help if you could attach package.json too

Comment: I will find my problem and solve it and also thanks to finding my error  @DNA.h

Comment: will be happy if i could provide any help

Comment: yes thanks for provide many information of signed apk release @DNA.h

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, change react-native to 0.59.3

run

> yarn add react-native@0.59.3

or

> npm i --save react-native@0.59.3

I also removed both **android/app/build** and **node_modules/** (To make a fresh build)

Apparently it's a bug associated with version 0.59.8