# How to be able to compile, run, and debug ReactNative app in Mac browser without running the Metro server?

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

I have a MacBook Air, and while it can perfectly compile and run ReactNative projects on Android device, I noticed that the MBA will become so hot in no time if the Metro server is run. If it's hot, even the IDE (Visual Studio Code) is lagging like 2-5s when I'm trying to type anything.

Is it possible for me to compile, run ReactNative project, and also debug it from Mac's browser, without running Metro server on my Mac? (like, for example, actually bundle the server into the app like when we release production APK -- but still enabling me to get console output on browser?)

EDIT: currently I have already added `bundleInDebug: true`, save, and then retry `npx react-native run-android`, but it still does the "Starting JS server..." thing. Closing the server terminal window makes the app crash, so I guess the app still depends on the Metro server on the computer. It's almost like the `bundleInDebug` option gets ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just edit `android/app/build/gradle`. Search for these lines

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]
```

And add `bundleInDebug: true` after `enableHermes` line.

If you have custom build variant, the configuration property can be in the following formats:

- `bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}`
- `bundleIn${buildType}`.

For example `bundleInFreeDebug: true`, `bundleInPaidRelease: true`, `bundleInBeta: true`

**EDIT:**
JS debugger works only with Metro server

Comment: Oh... yea, there's a large commented section on the `build.gradle` that explain just about that, but I never knew that that's the meaning. Now I have added it, and doing `npx react-native run-android`. But it still doing that "Starting js server..." operation. If I close the terminal window of the server, the app stop. Is there anything I missed? I've done further search and tried to do things listed here, but still no luck either. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39995118/3003927

Comment: Try to run the app from Android studio

Comment: Can I use command line? Because Android Studio is somewhat heavy weight to run and I use Visual Studio Code for my IDE.

Comment: Call `./gradlew installDebug` from `android` folder

Comment: Oh, yea, that works. So it's the `npx react-native run-android` that's causing the server to be initiated. Now I've got the app running on my device. But now it can't connect to the debugger on the browser of my computer. The browser debugger also report "Disconnected from server. Is node server running?" How can I fix this? I've tried to find some info first about this but can't find any. I tried to close the browser, close the app, and rerun it. Open the reactnative menu, and select debug. It shows error "Failed to connect to debugger! Unexpected end of stream on http://localhost:8081/..."

Comment: Usually when the the app is running connected to the metro server, when I select Debug option from react native app's menu, the browser in my Mac is automatically launched, even though it originally closed before.

Comment: You are right, JS debugger will not work with bundled code

Comment: :( ok thanks or the information. At least I learn something new.